# SQL Server : advanced computed column formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

A SQL table has a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` that contains the history of the customer statuses.

Example of value in `StatusHistory` column:

```
20120401P,20140715A,20160118T
```

Meaning:

- April 1, 2012 the customer was Pending
- July 15, 2015 the customer became Active
- January 18, 2016 the customer was Terminated

The status will ALWAYS be in chronological ascending order!

In the same table, I have a column called `CustStatus` in which I would like to store the CURRENT customer status by reading the `StatusHistory` column above based on `GETDATE()`.

Currently I am performing this with a formula in `CustStatus` that uses a user-defined function.

I might be wrong but I think that if I could do that without using a user-defined function, I could improve the performance of queries including this information.

So, would there be a formula that would allow me to populate `CustStatus` from reading `StatusHistory` based on `GETDATE()`?

Comment: This is a **horribly bad design!** Stop wasting your time trying to handle this - you need to **fix your design!**. You should have a `Customer` table with the current status, and a separate `CustomerHistory` table that references the `Customer` table and contains columns for the date and the status. With such a **properly relational** setup, querying will be a breeze !!

Comment: **Why do I keep getting answers like if my question was "Is the design good?"**. It's not what I asked! So I guess nobody knows how to do it.

Comment: @FrankM., because answering your actual question will encourage you to keep using it :)

Answer (score 1):

The design is pretty bad.  But, based on your specifications *and* assuming that you have no future statuses, you can get the most recent status pretty simply:

```
select right(StatusHistory, 1) as CurrentStatus
```

I strongly agree with marc_s that you should fix the design and have a `CustomerStatusHistory` table to store these properly.  But, if you cannot fix the data structure, at least this can help you get the information you need.

Note:  using `right()` would typically be much faster than a user defined function.

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. First of all, the string may receive future statuses. Also, I do have a separate status table and I was trying to find an alternative to avoid reading that table every time I need to retrieve the status for a given date. If I print a report with a passed date, I want the report to reflect the status on that date and same if I print the same report today or post dated.

Comment: Surely there must be a better way to do that and increase the performance of my queries at the same time. Open to any suggestions.